# Android default back action on statusbar

Tags: android, performance, react-native

I am working on a project where on the screens I want a title but not the back button which is by default in android I tried the following but unable to solve it.

```
static navigationOptions = {
  title: 'Please sign in',
  };
```

&&

```
static navigationOptions = {
headerTitle: 'Your Bmi details',
headerRight: (
 <Button
   onPress={() => alert('This is a button!')}
   title="Info"
   color="#fff"
 />
),
}}
```

I want both Title and Button on the title bar.i have attached the Screenshot please check it and help me with the solution.

[image]

Could someone help me with that?

Thanks.

Comment: What navigation do you use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For react-navigation, to make the back button disappear:

```
navigationOptions:  {
    title: 'Your Bmi details',
    headerRight: (
    <Button
    onPress={() => alert('This is a button!')}
    title="Info"
    color="#fff"
    />
    ),
    headerLeft: null
  }
```

Hope this helps!!

Answer (score 0):

In your AndroidManifest.xml file where you declared the activity like:

```
 <activity android:name=".SecondAvtivity"
        android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity">
```

just remove the parent activity name

```
 <activity android:name=".SecondAvtivity">
```

it should solve the problem

Comment: kurein,  i am actually working with React native and i am just using the Android emulator to run my project.